# override WPF styles

Tags: wpf, styles

Looking at SharpDevelop source code I found this button declaration:

```
<Button Style="{x:Static core:GlobalStyles.ButtonStyle}"
```

`Content="{core:Localize StartPage.StartMenu.NewCombineButton}" 
Click="newSolutionClick"  Margin="8,0,0,0" />`

my problem is the style declaration:  **Style="{x:Static core:GlobalStyles.ButtonStyle}"**
it prevents me from externally apply custom button style
if I remove the style declaration, the external theme (stored in .xaml) file works just fine.

my question: is there a way to override these specific style declarations?

Thanks a lot.
Adi Barda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `BasedOn` in your style... I've never used it with an x:Static so I'm not positive if it works or the syntax, but an example would be something like:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}" 
       BasedOn={StaticResource core:GlobalStyles.ButtonStyle}">

<!-- Style Button here - If you define a Setter that already 
     exists in base style it will overwrite it -->

</Style>
```